# Update warning: N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

Greetings Ubuntu Community,

When I try updating from the terminal today, I get the above titled warning. Not sure if it's okay to proceed or not, but here's the full update output from the terminal. `yay` is just an alias for `sudo apt update && sudo apt list --upgradable && sudo apt upgrade && flatpak update` btw :

```
scott@ubuntu:~$ yay
[sudo] password for scott: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]       
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]        
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]    
Ign:5 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                       
Get:6 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release [3,840 B]               
Get:7 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release.gpg [833 B]             
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [327 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [13.0 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [612 kB]
Get:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease [23.8 kB]
Get:12 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,157 B]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12.4 kB]
Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [93.1 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [427 kB]
Get:17 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [33.8 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [280 kB]
Get:19 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages [2,192 B]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [248 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12.5 kB]
Fetched 2,416 kB in 5s (496 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Listing... Done
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 27.11.2~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 27.10.1~22.04.1]
N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ubuntu-advantage-tools
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 163 kB of archives.
After this operation, 113 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

When I run the -a command, I get the following:

```
scott@ubuntu:~$ apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 27.11.2~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 27.10.1~22.04.1]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/now 27.10.1~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 27.11.2~22.04.1]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy 27.7~22.04.1 amd64
```

As you can see in the above command, I do have two PPAs for Vivaldi web browser and Papirus Icon Theme, both from their official source creators if that's at all relevant. Not sure if it's okay or safe to just update, but should I just press Y in the beginning and accept the update or is there any manual intervention that I may need to do?

Appreciate any help of course, thank you.

Comment: APT isn't complaining, merely informing. You can proceed.